# Opening Files Using Excel and VBA (on a Mac)

Tags: excel, vba, macos

After finishing the macro for my client, he informed me that he had a Mac. I have tried to adjust the code for Macs but I do not have a Mac to test it on. My friend with a Mac was trying to help me but he did not have any luck.

I need to find all the file names in the Matters folder and put them in column B.
I need to find all the file names in the RCTI folder and put them in column D.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I hoped this line of code would do the trick but it hasn't.

```
strFile = Dir(strPath, MacID("XLSX"))
```

My friend ran the macro and got an error. He couldn't really explain the error to me.

```
Matters = Range("B3").Text
strPath = Matters
strFile = Dir(strPath, MacID("XLSX"))
Row = 7
Do While strFile <> ""

    Range("B" & Row).Value = strFile
    Row = Row + 1
    strFile = Dir 'This moves the value of strFile to the next file.

Loop


Matters = Range("B3").Text
strPath = Matters
strFile = Dir(strPath, MacID("CSV"))
'strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")
Do While strFile <> ""

    Range("B" & Row).Value = strFile
    Row = Row + 1
    strFile = Dir 'This moves the value of strFile to the next file.

Loop


RCTI = Range("B4").Text
strPath = RCTI
strFile = Dir(strPath, MacID("XLSX"))
Row = 7
Do While strFile <> ""

    Range("D" & Row).Value = strFile
    Row = Row + 1
    strFile = Dir 'This moves the value of strFile to the next file.

Loop


RCTI = Range("B4").Text
strPath = RCTI
strFile = Dir(strPath, MacID("CSV"))
Do While strFile <> ""

    Range("D" & Row).Value = strFile
    Row = Row + 1
    strFile = Dir 'This moves the value of strFile to the next file.

Loop
```

---

Comment: Can you ask your friend for a screen cap of the error message? It would be very useful to see what the problem is

Comment: What error, on what line?

Comment: My friend said he got the error message - Error 5 Invalid procedure call or argument.

Comment: I think it was this line of code that gave him the error message - strFile = Dir(strPath, MacID("XLSX")).

Comment: I'm pretty sure ```"XLSX"``` isn't the right string. Based on the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/macid-function It looks to be ```"XLS#"``` where the # is a number corresponding to the file type. What that number is though I'm not sure, I've never used a mac and in classic fashion the docs are not complete with a list.

Comment: This might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292376/what-are-macid-filetypes-in-excel-vba